# Timer doesn't work in boolean

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my timer -

```
var myTimer = function () {
    var d = Date.now();
    // var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
    var timerSeconds = Math.round((od - d) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time left for this tour:" + timerSeconds;
    if (timerSeconds > 0) {
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    } else {
        finTour();
    }
};
myTimer();
```

it calls this function:

```
var finTour = function () {
    deleteCartes();
    randomCell();
    od = Date.now() + 5000;
    myTimer();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        tourOfComp();
    }, 5000)

    var tourOfComp = function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.backgroundColor == "aqua") {
                document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].firstChild.data = cartes[prochaineCarte++]
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("td")[j].style.backgroundColor == "aqua")
                document.getElementsByTagName("td")[j].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            tab[k].value = "";
        }
        od = Date.now() + timeFixe;
        myTimer();
    };
```

the problem is when I fix the time 20, it calls these two last function and the time is always 5 and never 20 it seems that it doesn`t renew the time, but only repeat this:

```
window.setTimeout(function ()
{
 tourOfComp();
},5000)
```

Comment: Use an `else` clause?

Comment: wht is od in you code??

Comment: If you don't call setTimeout again then you'll "stop the timer".

Comment: *"can I do something like this: if (myTimer ==0) callFunction2();"* ... that wouldn't make sense. `myTimer` is a **function** it it would never be equal to `0`.

Comment: Please replace the deprecated `arguments.callee` with simply `myTimer`!

Comment: @user2596685: Please [edit] your question to post additional code. In contrast to a comment you can format it there :-)